# How to suppress backtrace in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When exiting a Rails app using `raise` or `fail`, how to prevent the backtrace from being displayed?

Tried using `back_trace_limit` but it only seems to work for the console...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force ruby to hide backtrace on exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357383/force-ruby-to-hide-backtrace-on-exception)

Comment: It's the same question but the answer is different. Besides, the answer on the referenced question is 5 years old. There should be new and better approaches developed over such a great time span. I find that most answers that are 5 years old are no longer relevant, at least in certain areas such as Rails.

Comment: Oh, indeed. The answer is different. Then what about closing another one with link to this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have total control over the backtrace returned with an exception instance by using its `set_backtrace` method.  For example:

```
def strip_backtrace
  yield
rescue => err
  err.set_backtrace([])
  raise err
end

begin
  strip_backtrace do
    puts 'hello'
    raise 'ERROR!'
  end
rescue => err
  puts "Error message: #{err.message}"
  puts "Error backtrace: #{err.backtrace}"
end
```

Output:

```
hello
Error message: ERROR!
Error backtrace: []
```

The strip_backtrace method here catches all errors, sets the backtrace to an empty array, and re-raises the modified exception.

Comment: I would like to have seen the answer say it's not possible to suppress a stack trace without a workaround in Ruby as the answer. But also still provide this workaround

Comment: Further to this, `err.backtrace` is a mutable array and can be manipulated with standard array methods, including `select!` etc, `grep!` etc, and even `replace`. (However, `err.backtrace=` is _not_ a defined method, so that won't work.)